# WrapAll doesnt working in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```js
$('p').wrapAll($('<div class="wrapper"></div>'));
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background: #EEE;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test</p>
```

How we supposed to do same thing in react js!??
If i do something like this i am getting error msg **wrapall is not func**

Comment: ￼Using jquery in react js is bad practice. Changing the browser DOM using jquery means React is potentially no longer handling state, events and UI rendering.

Comment: so i want to figure out how to do this same thing(wrapall) in react js...

Comment: Do you create the p tags first, and then programmatically add the `<div class="wrapper">` around it? Can you just wrap the p tags within the wrapper element the first time round?

Comment: Actullay this one is just example code , real scenario is like there is videoJs plugin where already it creates dom where i should ve to wrap its internal dom... previously in jquery its easy to do but now in react m unable to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenter mentioned, you shouldn't really use jQuery and React together if you're doing DOM manipulation with both. That being said, for jQuery you should remove the `$(...)` around `<div class="wrapper"></div>`, like this:

```
$('p').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Also make sure you're typing `wrapAll` instead of `wrapall`. If you want to do the same in React, it kind of depends on the overall structure of your component. Without some context we can't really suggest much else. I can't really think of a reason why you would need to wrap an element after it's already been rendered and not just wrap it in your component's `render()` in the first place.

Comment: As you suggested *you shouldn't really use jQuery and React together*.
So how can we do this same thing in reactJS ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Like I said above, we need some more context as to what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it. Is there a reason you can't just wrap the `<p>` elements in a wrapper div in your `render()` function? Why can't you do the wrapping on the initial render?

Comment: Actullay this one is just example code , real scenario is am using videoJs plugin where plugin already creates dom so later on i should ve to wrap its internal dom by my custom div ...

Comment: You can create a child component and wrapped inside a parent component.    <div class="wrapper"><child-component /></div>